# Formatting an user input date.

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Is there a better way to format a date imputed by a user.  I have an input field where when clicked on a calender pops up and you can chose a date but the user also has the option to type in the date.  I want the user to be able to type in 1/12 and my javascript to format it to 01/12/2012. Is there an easy way to go about this with out having to do all types of checks? If not what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I just figured out a nice little fix that I'll post up here in a little while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just gave it a try but not sure if it's the proper way but I think it's working (month/day/year).

```
$('input[name="txt_date"]').on('blur', function(e){
    var dt=$(this).val();
    if(dt!='')
    {
        if(dt.indexOf('/'))
        {
            var da=dt.split('/');
            var l=da.length;
            if(l <= 3)
            {
                var date='';
                for(i=0;i<l;i++)
                {
                   if(i==0)
                   {
                      if(da[i].match(/^\d{1}|d{2}$/) && da[i]>0 && da[i]<=12)
                      {
                          var m=da[i].length==1 ? '0'+da[i] : da[i];
                          date=m;
                      }
                   }
                   if(i==1)
                   {
                       if(da[i].match(/^\d{1}|d{2}$/) && da[i]>0 && da[i]<=31)
                       {
                           var d=da[i].length==1 ? '0'+da[i] : da[i];
                           date+='/'+d;
                       }
                   }
                   if(i==2)
                   {
                       if(da[i].match(/^\d{4}$/))
                       {
                           date+='/'+da[i];
                       }
                       else date+='/'+new Date().getFullYear();
                   }
                }
                if(l<3)
                {
                    date+='/'+new Date().getFullYear();
                }
                if(date.match(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/))
                {
                    $(this).val(date);
                }
                else alert('invalid date!');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/JF4WT/)

Comment: the `for` cycle was a bit confusing at first - nice trick, but i would prefer a code without `for`, `if(i==0)` and `if(i==1)` + replace `if(i==2)` with `if(l===3)` + replace `if(l<3)` with `else`

Comment: Thanks for taking time to write that.  I do like that way but feel it becomes a bit unreadable with the regex.

Answer (score 3):

This library could help you: http://www.datejs.com/

dd/mm/yyyy is a valid format e.g. in Spain, UK, ...

Comment: datejs hasn't been updated in years. I found that http://momentjs.com/ is a much cleaner and updated implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.

```
var checkDate = function(dateVal, input){

            if(dateVal.length == 10){
                return;
            }
            var d = new Date();
            var currentMonth = d.getMonth();
            var year = d.getFullYear();
            var firstIndex = dateVal.indexOf('/');
            var month = parseInt(dateVal.substr(0, firstIndex));
            var day = parseInt(dateVal.substr(firstIndex + 1, 2));

            if(month < 10){
                month = '0' + month;
            }

            if(day < 10){
                day = '0' + day;
            }

            if(month > currentMonth){
                year = year - 1;
            }

            dateVal = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;

            if(isNaN(month)){
                input.val('');
                return;
            }
            input.val(dateVal);

        };
```

Comment: i prefer Sheikh Heera's answer, but if this captures all situations you want to, then it is a way to go

Comment: I added a few more small checks into it to legitimize it but yeah it does everything I need now.  I also like sheikh-heera's answer but really feel that way is to unreadable.